# Actionbarsherlock wont display menuitem in Android 4.x

Tags: java, android, xml, actionbarsherlock

I'm using actionbarsherlock as Actionbar. It works pretty good
under android 1.x and 2.x but after some testing I noticed that
the menuitems arent displaying in android 4.x.
Here's the xml of my menu items

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/overview_newgame"
    android:showAsAction="withText"
    android:title="@string/new_game"/>

</menu>
```

And this is how it looks like under android 4.x

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to use  setTheme(R.style.Theme_Sherlock) before super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) in your onCreate

Answer (score 0):

`withText` describes how the action item should be displayed but you have not specified *where* it should be displayed (hence it defaulting to `never` and going into the overflow menu).

If you would like it to show up on the action bar you should specify `ifRoom`.

See the [`setShowAsAction` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setShowAsAction%28int%29).

Comment: thanks for the response but that didn't worked. I specified my xml like this now. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/overview_newgame"
        android:title="@string/new_game"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|always|withText"
        android:visible="true"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"/>

</menu> is that what you ment

Comment: You should only specify one of `never`, `ifRoom`, or `always`.

Comment: yeah did that too. didn't worked either. I guess it has something to do with that android 4.0 skips the whole actionbarsherlock thing. because the title isn't changing too!